disabling mouse over text for \ref and \cite command in tagpdf
When  using \DocumentMetadata in the file, I am getting mouse over text for \ref and \cite command in the tagged pdf.
How to disable mouse over text for \ref{....} and \cite{....} 
on checking in the pdf management bundle I found the below macro in hgeneric-testphase.def for go to destination. When tries to modify this macro copied in my cls file but getting the below error, how to modify this in cls, also i am not able identify for cite mouse over link
! LaTeX socket Error: Plug 'default' for socket 'hyp/link/GoTo/Contents'
(socket)              already declared!

For immediate help type H <return>.

from hgeneric-testphase.def
\socket_new_plug:nnn {hyp/link/GoTo/Contents}{default}
  {
    \__hyp_text_pdfstring:eoN
      { Go~to~destination~#1  }
      { \l__hyp_text_enc_info_print_tl }
      \l__hyp_link_Contents_tl
  }

I am using latest version of tagpdf.sty and texlive-2024
MWE:
\DocumentMetadata
  {pdfversion=1.7,
   testphase={phase-III,table}
  }

\tagpdfsetup{role/map-tags=pdf}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}



\begin{document}

\title{Test title}


\maketitle


\section{Section title}\label{sec1}

Section~\ref{sec1}

\noindent \hyperref[sec1]{Section~\ref{sec1}}


\noindent \cite{bib1}

\noindent \cite{bib2,bib3}


\noindent \cite{bib1,bib2,bib3}




\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{bib1} bibliography text 1
\bibitem{bib2} bibliography text 2 
\bibitem{bib3} bibliography text 3 
\bibitem{bib4} bibliography text 4
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document} 


I think you meant mouse over, not move over in the title and question?

Yes, sorry for the typo. I’ve corrected it now

well you can change the text used in the tooltips (and I should improve the one used in the citation commands), but you can't get rid of the text altogether if you want to produce a UA-compliant document.  There must be something in the /Contents key that describes the link for accessibility and some viewer then show that as tooltip.

Note that depending on the viewer you get different text here - on macOS I get three different outcomes with Acrobat, Preview and TeXworks

@UlrikeFischer, thank you for clarifying, i can modify for \ref{...}  using \socket_new_plug:nnn {hyp/link/GoTo/Contents}{default}, but for \cite{...} the changes are not reflected in the PDF, and it still shows 'ref' on mouse-over. I am stuck and unable to find a solution.
i am stuck and unable to get the solution

It would be useful to know the motivation here - as @UlrikeFischer says, this is not compliant with the standard

You can remove the Contents entry from the annotation dictionary with hooks. But this is not standard compliant to PDF/UA. Use \ref* inside \hyperref to avoid nested links warnings.
\DocumentMetadata
  {pdfversion=1.7,
   testphase={phase-III,table}
  }

\tagpdfsetup{role/map-tags=pdf}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% the hyp/link/link hook is not predeclared so it must be initialized
\IfHookExistsTF{hyp/link/link}{}
   {\NewHook{hyp/link/link}}
\AddToHook{hyp/link/link}
 { 
   \pdfannot_dict_remove:nn {link/GoTo}{Contents}
 }
\AddToHook{hyp/link/cite}
 { 
   \pdfannot_dict_remove:nn {link/GoTo}{Contents}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\title{Test title}


\maketitle


\section{Section title}\label{sec1}

Section~\ref{sec1}

\noindent \hyperref[sec1]{Section~\ref*{sec1}}


\noindent \cite{bib1}

\noindent \cite{bib2,bib3}


\noindent \cite{bib1,bib2,bib3}


\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{bib1} bibliography text 1
\bibitem{bib2} bibliography text 2 
\bibitem{bib3} bibliography text 3 
\bibitem{bib4} bibliography text 4
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}


Note that some viewers still show a tooltip here - it's outside of the control of the PDF producer.

@UlrikeFischer, its working perfect, thanks for your valuable help.
